# Confusion with multiple interface implementation

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface, refactoring

I have the following set of Interfaces and Classes.

```
public interface IValidatableObject
{
   List<string> ValidationErrors { get; }
   bool Validate();
}

public class ValidatableObject : IValidatableObject
{
   public List<string>ValidationErrors { get; }
   public bool Validate()
   {
      //dostuff
   }
}

public interface IDeviceDataObject
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceDataObject : ValidatableObject, IDeviceDataObject
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceService
{
   public bool ValidateDevice(IDeviceDataObject device)
   {
       return device.Validate(); // This throws a compiler error
   }
}
```

The problem in the service operation ValidateDevice above is that the compiler can't resolve device.Validate() because IDeviceDataObject does not implement the IValidatableObject interface.

My question is, is it then correct to change `IValidatableObject` to implement `IValidatableObject`. I'm a little uncertain as to whether this is good practice because the way I kind of see it, `DeviceDataObject` is implementing `IValidatableObject` twice - once through `ValidatableObject` and once through `IDeviceDataObject`. Can anyone help clear this up for me?

```
public interface IDeviceDataObject : IValidatableObject
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why doesnt your ValidateDevice signature look like ``public bool ValidateDevice(IValidatableObject someobj)``? Isnt that what expresses the functionality of a validating method: it takes something that is validatable. Everything else could stay the way it is.

Comment: Fair call. But what if it was a CreateDevice method that needed to know that it was a IDeviceDataObject being passed in but it still needed to have IValidatableObject functionality?

Comment: So - because I dont know the bigger picture here - should all IDeviceDataObjects be validatable? If yes, let ``IDeviceDataObject`` inherit from ``IValidatableObject``. If not, then this is no solution. It is sometimes really that simple: it is just a matter of what makes sense semantically. Translating this into code in turn is then a rather simple step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may understand something wrong here (and I dont know your class architecture as a whole), but why doesn't your ValidateDevice method just take validatable objects? The signature would look like:

```
public bool ValidateDevice(IValidatableObject someobj)
```

Isnt that what expresses the functionality of a method that does *validation*: it takes something that is *validatable*. Everything else could stay the way it is (i.e. dont let `IDeviceDataObject` inherit from `IValidatableObject`, as you may want to express that not every devicedataobject is also validatable for example)

A second way, if you want to make sure that `ValidateDevice` only takes objects implementing `IDeviceDataObject`, you could also try to cross-cast to `IValidatableObject`:

```
public bool ValidateDevice(IDeviceDataObject someobj)
{
    if(someobj is IValidatableObject)
    {
        return ((IValidatableObject)device).Validate();
    }
    return //something that makes sense if the device is not validatable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply cast to IValidatableObject.

```
public class DeviceService 
{ 
   public bool ValidateDevice(IDeviceDataObject device) 
   { 
       IValidatableObject v = device as IValidatableObject;

       if (v != null)
           return device.Validate();
       return false;
   } 
}
```

Comment: But all devices that are in valid state but do not implement `IValidatableObject` will fail the validation.

Comment: @Eranga - And?  The only way they can notify of being valid is to implement IValidatableObject.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: the API is lying. I would expect `ValidateDevice` method to do the validation based on `IDeviceDataObject` contract. I would have to go through the implementation of the `ValidateDevice` know that I have to implement `IValidatableObject` also.

Comment: @Eranga - No, the API is not lying.  The object can't be validated if it doesn't implement IValidatableObject.  It's that simple.  To solve your problem, there's this thing called "documentation".

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `ValidateDevice` method generic to leave it up to the caller to pass in object instances that implement the right combinations of interfaces - this would allow your interfaces to remain independent and still enforce type safety:

```
public class DeviceService
{
   public bool ValidateDevice<T>(T device) where T: IDeviceDataObject, IValidatableObject
   {
       return device.Validate(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring a lot from the names, but it looks to me as if `IDeviceDataObject` and `IValidatableObject` are separate ideas.  It seems reasonable that you could have objects which implement either `IDeviceDataObject`, `IValidatableObject`, or both (yes?).  If this is true, then there is no "is a" relationship between the two interfaces (you wouldn't assume `IDeviceDataObject` is a `IValidatableObject`), so inheriting one interface from the other seems wrong.

As for your `ValidateDevice` method (or any method) -- if it's going to use the argument as a `IDeviceDataObject`, the argument should be of that type.  If it's going to use the argument as an `IValidatableObject`, the argument should be of *that* type.  If it might use both pieces of functionality, you might want to pass in a less specific type and then do a runtime check (using C# 'is' or 'as') to see if the object supports the particular interface.